# Selenium Open Local Files

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to use a Firefox/Selenium instance as a rudimentary slideshow for images.  The idea is that I will open a `webdriver` and `driver.get()` files from a local directory.

When I run the following, I receive an error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection`

My assumption is that selenium is attempting to test the next `driver.get()` request and is not allowing a local, non web-connected, connection is there a way to bypass this behavior?  My code example appears below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from os import listdir
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

image_source = '/home/pi/Desktop/slideshow/photo_frames/daniel/images/'

for file in listdir(image_source):
    if file.endswith('jpg'):
        file_name = image_source + file
        driver.get(file_name)
        time.sleep(5)
```

UPDATE:
I should add that the same basic script structure works for websites - I can loop through several websites without any errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are just need to add `file://` to the filename. This works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from os import listdir
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def main():
    image_source = '/home/pi/Desktop/slideshow/photo_frames/daniel/images/'

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        for file in listdir(image_source):
            if file.endswith('jpg'):
                file_name = 'file://' + image_source + file
                driver.get(file_name)
                time.sleep(5)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you - this does work.  I want to believe I tried adding 'file://' to the beginning of the address, but your example definitely functions in the desired way.

Comment: The above won't work for local html. The code gets stuck if I try this with local html.

Comment: @Niklas Adding 'file://' allowed me to open a local HTML file within Ubuntu 22.04. I did need to provide the full path to the HTML file, not just a relative one.

Answer (score 11):

This can also be done with Pathlib

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
html_file = Path.cwd() / "relative//path//to//file.html"
browser.get(html_file.as_uri())
```

If you are new to pathlib then the / syntax can look a bit odd, but it's very easy to use, here is a good tutorial https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/

Answer (score 10):

If you came in here wanting Selenium to serve your local html file, as I did, the above-mentioned accepted answer needs a tiny modification for it to work, as noticed by [Niklas Rosencrantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/niklas-rosencrantz).

For Selenium to serve local html in your browser, and assuming the file is in your current working directory, try this (I'm on a Windows, using Selenium 3.141.0 and Python 3.7 - if it matters to you):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
html_file = os.getcwd() + "//" + "relative//path//to//file.html"
browser.get("file:///" + html_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

An edit from [Dan
Heaford's](/users/1473282/dan-heaford) anwser to open local html file:

Html: `<body><h1>I'm an h1</h1></body>`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path
chrome_driver_path = "#'** Dir where you saved your 
                       chromedriver.exe**'/Users/ASUS/chromedriver"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
html_file = Path.cwd() / "#html file Dir.html"
browser.get(html_file.as_uri())

heading1 = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')
print(heading1.text)
result in console - "I'm an h1"
```