# Selenium 3.5 closing local files with Firefox 55.0.3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium 3.5 for Python to test some behaviors of my web app using both local pages and online ones. 
Until now, I just used Chrome as main browser to test it and everything works fine. Then, I decided to use Firefox 55.0.3 using geckodriver v0.19.0.
I have the following issues:

1. selenium opens the local pages such as `file:///PATH/index.html` but it doesn't close the browser even using the function `quit()`;
2. I would use some browser option such as the incognito mode, but I was not able to find a list of all available options for Firefox.

This is a snippet of my code to use selenium with Firefox.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
#url = 'file:///PATH/index.html'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.quit() 
# borser.close() -> I also tried with the close()
```

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950789/selenium-open-local-files) for the first issue but it doesn't work with the current version of the used framework.
About the second I can only find partial solution such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082656/how-might-i-simulate-a-private-browsing-experience-in-watir-selenium) for the incognito mode but it doesn't work as expected.

Any ideas? Is it a kind of bug in geckodriver?

Comment: It could be a bug but as a workaround you could just go to a `browser.get("about:blank")` and then try quit

Comment: Hey @TarunLalwani, your solution works fine when i open a real URL like the first one in the example code. Unfortunately, I tried with the local webpage (the second URL in the example) and it doesn't work. The browser stalls on the local page without opening the blank one.

Comment: Open an issue with geckodriver repo and see they have some insights